# jquery get height of inline element working only in Firefox

Tags: jquery

How to preperly get height of inline element which has multiple elements inside of it.
See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ue6nW/) for example. This only works propperly in Firefox, but not in other browsers. In other browsers it only gets the height of text before h2.
What could be the problem? The wrapper needs to be inline element.

example here:

```
<div class="inline-element" style="display: inline">This is a sample text for an inline element. How to determin the height on entire element if it has more elements inside. Thanks.This is a sample text for an inline element. How to determin the height on entire element if it has more elements inside. Thanks.<h2>This is a title inside inline element</h2><p>This is a paragraph inside inline element</p>This is a sample text for an inline element. How to determin the height on entire element if it has more elements inside. Thanks.</div>
```

And jquery code:

```
var height = $('.inline-element').height();

console.log(height);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is because of a common rule: You may not place block elements in inline elements. You can not add a `div` in a `span`, but you can add a `span` in a `div`. If you were to test your code in a html-validator, it would be fine, but because you use the inline styling to set it to inline manually, it will cause unpredictable behaviour.

---

You can use [`.innerHeight()`](https://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) or [`.outerHeight()`](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/):

```
// Without padding,border and margin
var height = $('.inline-element').innerHeight();

// WITH padding,border and margin 
var height = $('.inline-element').outerHeight();
```

You can also get the css value (but I doubt you want that). If you want to get the height of css:

```
// The css value of height with jQuery
var height = $('.inline-element').css('height');
```

Comment: No, i have tried it, this doesnt work, you can test it your self in fiddle, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: So there is no way to get height propperly for inline element with other elements inside?

Comment: You could make it relative, add two 1x1 absolute divs to it, one top:0, other bottom:0, and use `offset()` to calc the difference

Comment: Good thinking for the offset. It however doesn't work great because top absolute div does not position well because of h2. But i am using some wrapper div which i can use to position the top div based on it.Thanks.